# c# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory - the process cannot access the file "path_to_the_zip_file_created.zip" because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net

Basic Code:

```cs
string startPath = @"C:\intel\logs";
string zipPath = @"C:\intel\logs-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_dd_M-HH_mm_ss") + ".zip";
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
```

> Error: the process cannot access the file "path_to_the_zip_file_created.zip" because it is being used by another process.

The above setup works fine on windows 7 where I have Visual Studio installed but I get the above error message when running on Windows Server 2008R2.

I have checked the antivirus logs and it does not block the application, nor does it lock the zip file that is created.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: This is exactly what is happening to me.

Comment: The zip file is trying to zip all of the contents of the folder, but is written while still reading the folder. This causes it to try to zip itself. The answers below demonstrate that you must not store the zip file within the folder you are zipping.

Comment: @KyleShrader No, he is zipping 'logs' in 'intel' and placing the result into 'intel'.

Answer (score 134):

```
//WRONG
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:\somefolder", "C:\somefolder\somefile.zip");
//RIGHT     
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:\somefolder", "C:\someotherfolder\somefile.zip");
```

I use to do the same error: **zipping a file into the same folder that I'm zipping**.
This causes an error, of course.

Comment: @EmauneleGreco Is it possible to include destination in other drive? For Ex: `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:\somefolder", "D:\someotherfolder\somefile.zip");` like this? My motto here is to create zipped file in other drive

Comment: such a "duh" point when you realize solution so obvious....thanks

Answer (score 24):

I came across this while because I was trying to zip the folder where my log files were being actively written by a running application. Kyle Johnson's answer could work, but it adds the overhead of copying the folder and the necessity of cleaning up the copy afterwards. Here's some code that will create the zip even if log files are being written to:

```
void SafelyCreateZipFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, string zipFilePath)
{
    using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Create))
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryName))
        {
            var entryName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryName);
            entry.LastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
            using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            {
                fs.CopyTo(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was facing the same situation, Thanks for clean solution

Comment: This works for my requirements. I modified this code: Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryName).Where(f => f.EndsWith(".zip") == false). This way the newly created zip file is not included in this bunch.

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same problem. The workaround is to copy the folder you are zipping to another folder and point CreateFromDirectory there. Don't ask me why this works but it does.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(<new directory path>);
File.Copy(<copy contents into new folder>);
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(<new folder path>, <zipPath>);
```

Comment: You could also try _not writing the zipfile in the directory being zipped_.

Comment: Yuo genius @CodeCaster .. me silly trying to zip file into the same folder!

Comment: For me, this answer is correct when attempting to backup a site. The only files being locked by the process are the log files (thanks, Log4Net!), which I don't care about for backups.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers, provide the correct reason, but I had a little problem in understanding them at the first sight.

If the path of the Zip file that is being created, is the same as the path that is given to the ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory, the ZipFile creates the desired zip file and starts adding the files from the directory to it. And will Eventually, try to add the desired zip file in the zip as well, as it is in the same directory. This is just not possible and not required, because the desired zipfile is being used by CreateFromDirectory method.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting this error because NLog is locking your log files, you can use the following workaround.  Add 'keepFileOpen' attribute to your nlog tag inside NLog.config and set it to false:

```
<nlog xmlns=.......
   keepFileOpen="false"
....>
```

More details [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2750).

Note that this setting will have negative performance on NLog logging as indicated [here](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target).