# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory throws System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file X because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, directory, ioexception, zip

Actually I'm trying to create zip file of a directory and but the `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()` giving below Exception.

> System.IO.IOException :   The process cannot access the file
>   PATH_TO_CREATE_ZIP/file.zip' because it is being used by another
>   process.

Following is the Code Snippet for it. :

```
public void createZipFile(string zipPath, string archiveFileName)
{
    string DirectoryToBeArchive = zipPath + "\\" + archiveFileName;

    if (Directory.Exists(DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip"))
    {
        File.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive);
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipPath, DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
    }
    else
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipPath, DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);

    Directory.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive);
}
```

Help Would be Much Appreciated. Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory - the process cannot access the file "path\_to\_the\_zip\_file\_created.zip" because it is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395128/c-sharp-zipfile-createfromdirectory-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-path-t)

Comment: And look into `Path.Combine` and `Path.ChangeExtension`

Comment: You are trying to archive a directory and place the zip in the same directory you are archiving. Ofcourse you will get this error, change the path of the zip file to another directory

Comment: Actually I'm Trying to archive a directory and placing it in its immediate parent Directory.

E-G : Path : DirA / DirB / DirC  : I want to Zip DirC and place it in DirB. this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: My Code is although zipping the file and placing it in right directory but also it is giving me the exception too.

Comment: @Haider Did you have the chance to check my answer? If it solved the issue, please mark it as answer. If it didn't, let me know.

Comment: Don't use the same folder for the zip as the source folder of the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only makes sense you get this exception. Let's investigate your code step by step:

```
createZipFile("C:\\Temp", "myZipFile");

public void createZipFile(string zipPath, string archiveFileName)
{
    //DirectoryToBeArchive = "C:\\Temp\\myZipFile"
    string DirectoryToBeArchive = zipPath + "\\" + archiveFileName;

    //Some logical error here, you probably meant to use File.Exists()
    //Basically, as you can't find a directory with name C:\\Temp\\myZipFile.zip, you always jump into else
    if (Directory.Exists(DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip"))
    {
        File.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive);
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipPath, DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
    }
    else
        //It will try to overwrite your existing "DirectoryToBeArchive".zip file 
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipPath, DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);

    //This won't work as well btw, as there probably is no directory 
    //with name C:\\Temp\\myZipFile
    Directory.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive);
}
```

Though, even if you delete the file, you will probably hit same error.
The thing is when you try zipping the folder `C:\\Temp` into the file `C:\\Temp\\myZipFile.zip` you will also try zipping the file itself. That's actually where you get the file is being used error.

So,

1. Replace Directory.Exists() with File.Exists()
2. Zip in another folder
3. Just a friendly warning, I'd be cautious with Directory.Delete() if I were you :)

Comment: *I'd be cautious with Directory.Delete()* You speak out of experience of just hearsay?

Comment: Out of experience. Also, he is probably trying to delete the folder where the actual zip file is, along with all other files that he's trying to zip :) 
So in the end, he will have nothing in hand

Comment: Well I will have the zipped file at the end.

keeping both folder and the zip file doesn't make sense. in future if i would needed the data I will just extract the zip one. :)

Comment: @Haider That's because `Directory.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive);` in your code does not do anything at all. As there is probably no directory with the name `PATH_TO_CREATE_ZIP/file` as per your example. That was just a heads up for you, in order to prevent unintended deletion of the folder. Btw, I believe my answer of using `File.Exists()` instead of `Directory.Exists()` helped you to solve the issue. Could u please mark it as Answer if it did? Ty

Comment: right before 10 mints of reading your answer I figure out exactly these things and make them right in my code..

But as your answer was quite helpful. so I'm gonna mark it.
Thanks for the help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was, the output folder and zipping folder was the same.
Moved to separate folders, now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code :

this piece of code after little correction worked for me..

```
string DirectoryToBeArchive = zipPath + "\\" + archiveFileName;

            if (File.Exists(DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip"))
            {
                File.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip");
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DirectoryToBeArchive, DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
            }
            else
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DirectoryToBeArchive, DirectoryToBeArchive + ".zip", CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);

            Directory.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive , true);
```