# keep folder permission when compress in c#

Tags: c#, zip

I need to compress some folders in a directory using c#. the issue that some folders inside the directory are read-only (write is not allowed), after making the compression the permission is missed. any help, please?
simply I am using the following code to compress

```
 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(my_data, new_folder);
```

Comment: This is not about setting the "compressed' Attribute to a Folder, as a feature of the filesystem ? You just do a copy of your files, and compress it to another location ? So the read-only flag is not a topic at all, you do read only.

Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395128/c-sharp-zipfile-createfromdirectory-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-path-t
Is your target file, inside the directory you try to store ? That's wrong.

Comment: What zip utility are you using?  Does it have a credential option?