# Getting exception while zip files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, zip

I have a method that convert my bytes to files then zip that files:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MultipleGet(MultipleProofOfDeliverySelectModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            async Task<IActionResult> DoMultipleGet()
            {
                var rModel = await _MyService.MultipleGet(model);
         
                var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                var loggedUserName = Environment.UserName;
                var filePath = $"C:\\Users\\{loggedUserName}\\Test\\";
                var zipPath = $"C:\\Users\\{loggedUserName}\\Test\\test_{today}.zip";

                var fileExistIterator = 1;
                foreach (var file in rModel)
                {
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists($"{filePath}{file.Name}"))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes($"{filePath}{file.Name}", file.File);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes($"{filePath}{fileExistIterator}{file.Name}", file.File);
                        fileExistIterator++;
                    }
                }


                //HERE IS THE ISSUE
               ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filePath, zipPath);

                return Ok(zipPath);

            }
            return await DoMultipleGet();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Problem is when application Zip files `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filePath, zipPath);` it do the process but return an exception

> The process cannot access the file test_20200708.zip' because it is
> being used by another process.

Why that happen if I use only that method and no other do something with that files?

Comment: You're writing the zipfile into the folder you're zipping.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304636/5817136